# Defining a constant string containing non printable character in C

Tags: c

I want to define a constant string containing non printable characters in C. For e.g - Let say I have a string

```
char str1[] ={0x01, 0x05, 0x0A, 0x15};
```

Now I want to define it like this

```
char *str2 = "<??>"
```

What should I write in place of `<??>` do define an string equivalent to `str1`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `"\x01\x05\x0a\x15"`

Comment: +1, except for the fact that it will have an extra, terminating null appended to it.

Comment: @roe: But since the OP says that he wants a "string" (and not a `char` array), to me that means it needs a NUL terminator.

Comment: @jamesd; I know, hence the +1, just wanted to point out that it will add an extra 0-byte to it, so they'll probably be equivalent for most intents and purposes, but won't be strictly equal.

Comment: At the risk of sounding petty, my answer is better because of this. :)

Comment: Sound very petty

Answer (score 3):

You could use :

`const char *str2 = "\x01\x05\x0A\x15";`

See [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28VS.80%29.aspx) on MSDN (couldn't find a *more neutral* link).

Comment: I find a more formal link on cppreference.com: [Escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) .

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use both a string literal and avoid having an extra terminator (NUL character) added, do it like this:

```
static const char str[4] = "\x1\x5\xa\x15";
```

When the string literal's length *exactly* matches the declared length of the character array, the compiler will not add the terminating NUL character.

The following test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  size_t i;
  static const char str[4] = "\x1\x5\xa\x15";

  printf("str is %zu bytes:\n", sizeof str);
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof str; ++i)
    printf("%zu: %02x\n", i, (unsigned int) str[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Prints this:

```
str is 4 bytes:
0: 01
1: 05
2: 0a
3: 15
```

I don't understand why you would prefer using this method rather than the much more readable and maintainable original one with the hex numbers separated by commas, but perhaps your real string contains normal printable characters too, or something.

Comment: Interesting. Is this in the standard?

Comment: @row: Yes, absolutely. It is not the same in C++ though, but for C it is standard behaviour.